# LIRC - Unable to load module

Tags: modules, lirc

I have rasbian installed and I'm trying to use LIRC to read from a remote control following this tutorial.

http://mvartan.com/2014/11/25/controlling-your-tv-or-any-ir-device-with-raspberry-pi/

I have successfully created a remote control configuration using `irrecord`. I have saved the configuration to `/etc/lirc/lircd.conf`

When I attempt to start the lirc process, I get this error

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt# /etc/init.d/lirc start --verbose
[ ok ] Loading LIRC modules:.
[FAIL] Unable to load LIRC kernel modules. Verify your ... failed!
[FAIL] selected kernel modules in /etc/lirc/hardware.conf ... failed!
```

Contents of /etc/modules

```
snd-bcm2835
lirc_dev
mceusb
lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=23 gpio_out_pin=22
```

Contents of /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

```
# /etc/lirc/hardware.conf
#
# Arguments which will be used when launching lircd
LIRCD_ARGS=""

#Don't start lircmd even if there seems to be a good config file
#START_LIRCMD=false

#Don't start irexec, even if a good config file seems to exist.
#START_IREXEC=false

#Try to load appropriate kernel modules
LOAD_MODULES=true

# Run "lircd --driver=help" for a list of supported drivers.
DRIVER="default"
# usually /dev/lirc0 is the correct setting for systems using udev 
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_dev,mceusb"

# Default configuration files for your hardware if any
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

Output of `lsmod`

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
snd_bcm2835            21149  0 
snd_pcm                90778  1 snd_bcm2835
snd_seq                61097  0 
snd_seq_device          7209  1 snd_seq
snd_timer              23007  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    66325  5 snd_bcm2835,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_seq_device
evdev                  11000  2 
ir_lirc_codec           5056  0 
ir_xmp_decoder          2925  0 
lirc_dev               11060  1 ir_lirc_codec
ir_mce_kbd_decoder      4248  0 
ir_sharp_decoder        2201  0 
ir_sanyo_decoder        2433  0 
ir_sony_decoder         2206  0 
ir_jvc_decoder          2179  0 
ir_rc6_decoder          2755  0 
ir_rc5_decoder          2259  0 
ir_nec_decoder          2603  0 
rc_rc6_mce              1365  0 
mceusb                 10119  0 
rc_core                23526  14 ir_sharp_decoder,ir_xmp_decoder,lirc_dev,ir_lirc_codec,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,mceusb,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_sanyo_decoder,rc_rc6_mce
uio_pdrv_genirq         3666  0 
uio                     9897  1 uio_pdrv_genirq
```

The receiver and transmitter that I am using [is this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00066FIO6).

I am able to read from remote controls, but not start the `lirc` service.

How can I get this service to start, and load these modules?

Comment: I created an extensive [tutorial](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70945/setting-up-a-remote-control-using-lirc) on stackexchange on how I managed to remote control my TV using only a Raspberry Pi and an old Infrared diode from an old remote control.

Answer (score 2):

The configuration is wrong, `MODULES` should be separated with a space, not a comma.

Incorrect

```
MODULES="lirc_dev,mceusb"
```

Correct

```
MODULES="lirc_dev mceusb"
```